# AWS ElasticSearch with cakephp/elastic-search plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, aws-sdk

I would like to know how to configure AWS ElasticSearch with cakephp/elastic-search plugin(https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search).

cakephp/elastic-search plugin uses Elastica to connect to ElasticSearch, so it should be possible to connect to AWS's one too, but I have no idea how to make it possible.

I use ElasticSearch 6.2 and cakephp/elastic-search 2.0.0-beta

Any help is sincerely appreciated.